# How well does Metroid Other M take advantage of the Wiimote's unique features?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wiimote, metroid-other-m

Since I am near the end of *Metroid Prime 3: Corruption* for the Nintendo Wii, I am considering new games for me to play next. I am interested in *Metroid: Other M*, but I want to know *without spoliers* how well it takes advantage of the Wii's unique capabilities.

For example: *Metroid Prime 3: Corruption* has certain moves Samus can perform which are invoked by "flicking" the Wiimote or by casting the Nunchuck in various ways. Interaction with various objects requires unique and semi-accurate motion of the Wiimote. Also, certain monsters require you to shake the Wiimote to escape their grasp, and the game uses a point-and-shoot interface of the Wiimote for aiming. However, *Metroid Prime 3: Corruption* does not take advantage of the Wiimote's ability to play sound.

As opposed to a game like *A Boy and His Blob* for the Wii, which doesn't take advantage of the Wiimote's capabilities in any form.

**Without spoliers**, how well does *Metroid: Other M* advantage of the Wiimote's unique features?

Comment: I would recommend Super Mario Galaxy 1&2 before Other M, just because they are significantly better games. And this comes from someone who's been a big Metroid fan since 1988.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://www.gamesradar.com/wii/metroid-other-m/preview/metroid-other-ms-quirky-controls-explained/a-20100323125139224062/g-20090602105555875007) on Games Radar explains how the controls are used.

You only use the remote (no nunchuck) and it's used sideways for most of the time, though there are occasions when you need to point the remote at the screen:

> Most of the time, you hold the remote sideways, like an old-school NES controller. Pointing the remote at the screen puts Samus into visor mode. The B trigger pans the camera unless locking on with A, in which case it fires a missile. The D-pad cycles through weapons while aiming.

So basically the only unique feature it uses is the camera to move the cursor around the screen. There's no motion control in this game.

There are screen shots, but they don't give anything away.

Comment: Thanks Chris! That's a shame (I think) because the Wii's biggest advantage is the unique controls!

Comment: @Josh - I think part of the reason is that a different developer was given this game.